# Comment utilise-t-on le mot « media » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, pluriel, latin

Si je voulais dire « the media creates a narrative of events », comment pourrais-je le traduire ?

> Les *médias* créent un narratif d'événements.
>   ou
>
> Le *média* crée un narratif d'événements.
>   ou
>
> Les *média* créent un narratif d'événements.

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: If you were indeed saying in english « the media creates a narrative of events », would it not be faulty ? *media* comes from the latin plural form of *medium*, and is to be treated [as a plural](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/media) in english. I must admit I thought it was the same in french, where I personnaly used medium for the singular form since a long time. I thank you for this question, I now learned that the french usage has changed, *un média* is now the prefered singular form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le pluriel de média est *médias* . Le verbe doit suivre le nom, donc c'est *créent*. En français il n'y a pas un narratif d'événements mais un *récit d'événements*.
Donc c'est :

> Les médias créent un récit d'événements.

Comment: Bonsoir :)  Est-ce que <<les medias>> insinue <<the mass media>> en anglais?

Comment: « Media » sans s s’emploie également comme pluriel.

Comment: Est-ce qu'on aurait pu parler au figuré d'une [narration](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/narration) des événements ici ?

Answer (score 2):

*Media* (english) / *média* (french) comes from the (latin) plural form of *medium*, and [french](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/media) and [english](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/media) languages have initially retained these forms.

With the *francisation totale* in 1983, *média* has become the regular singular form in french.

Comment: À l'appui: [ici](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/CULT477?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=media&francetermeSearchDomaine=0), et [là](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17009002).

Comment: @Amphiteóth Merci pour les références ! ;-)